# How can we get data of internet Application wise Usage in Andorid?

Tags: android, mobile, wifi

How can I get Data of Mobile/Wi-Fi Internet Application wise usage data In Android?

Example: 
I want data like **ApplicationName, UsageVia(Mobile/Wi-Fi), DataUsage(KB)**

Comment: Have you tried anything ?

Comment: i have googled it out but find nothing.

Comment: There is a method which provides the details you are asking in question.

Comment: Checkout [TrafficStats](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/TrafficStats.html) API.

Comment: How can i get application name & usage via?